# Ordering Ivy dependencies

Tags: ivy

I'm struggling to get my head around the exact behaviour of exclusions in Ivy.

In the following Ivy file, why does putting `commons-logging` before `log4j` pull in `javax.activation` and `javax.mail` from `log4j` whereas putting it after doesn't.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="test" module="test" />

    <configurations defaultconfmapping="default->runtime(*)" />

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.15">
            <exclude org="javax.activation" />
            <exclude org="javax.mail" />
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1" />

        <exclude org="com.sun.jdmk" />
        <exclude org="com.sun.jmx" />
        <exclude org="javax.jms" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Answer (score 4):

The activation and mail jars are dependencies of commons logging, yet you've excluded them on the log4j dependency...

When you only use a single configuration this sends a mixed message to ivy, should they be excluded or not? The following would be a lot more explicit:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.15"/>
    <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1" />

    <exclude org="javax.activation" />
    <exclude org="javax.mail" />    
    <exclude org="com.sun.jdmk" />
    <exclude org="com.sun.jmx" />
    <exclude org="javax.jms" />
</dependencies>
```

It's less confusing when the excludes are set globally.

If you want to keep the dependency resolution separate then you'll need to set up more than one configuration (think of these as dependency sets):

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="test" module="test" />

    <configurations>
       <conf name="log4j_deps" description="log4j dependencies"/>
       <conf name="commons_deps" description="commons-logging dependencies"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.15" conf="log4j_deps->runtime">
            <exclude org="javax.activation" />
            <exclude org="javax.mail" />
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="1.1" conf="commons_deps->runtime"/>

        <exclude org="com.sun.jdmk" />
        <exclude org="com.sun.jmx" />
        <exclude org="javax.jms" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Switching around the dependency tags will have no effect now, because the dependency resolution is explicit.

- Log4j and its dependencies are associated with the **log4j_deps** configuration
- commons dependencies are placed onto the **commons_deps** configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will use a global exclusion. I'd still be interested to know the mechanics behind why they're excluded one way around and not the other.

Comment: @ICR I explained this.... You're using a single configuration and asking for a dependency to be excluded on a different dependency... confusing ivy.... Should it be in? or should it be out?.... That's why the global exclusion works better removes the ambiguity.